filter array in Google Script, but returns only one row
I created an array and i want to filter it
The array has
responseTimeStamp in Col0,
TargetDate in Col1,
Data in Col2-Col5,
and for testing same responseTimeStamp in Col6 (DisplayValue),
and for testing same responseTimeStamp in Col7 (converted),
These columns are retrieved separately and then put together in one array
There are multiple responses per TargetDate (each set consists of 19 entries), and each response has a timestamp
from all of the raw data i want to find the TargetDates and for each TargetDate I need all the latest entries
Here is the way i went:
  var numRows = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getLastRow()-1;
  var DataFeedbackCo1_Col0 = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getRange(2,1,numRows,1).getValues();
  var DataFeedbackCo1_Col0Time = new Array ();
  DataFeedbackCo1_Col0.map(function(Dat){{DataFeedbackCo1_Col0Time.push([Dat[0]*1 ] ) } });
  var DataFeedbackCo1_Col0Display = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getRange(2,1,numRows,1).getDisplayValues();
  var DataFeedbackCo1_Col1 = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getRange(2,2,numRows,1).getDisplayValues();
  var DataFeedbackCo1_Col2 = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getRange(2,3,numRows,1).getDisplayValues();
  var DataFeedbackCo1_Col3 = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getRange(2,4,numRows,1).getDisplayValues();
  var DataFeedbackCo1_Col4 = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getRange(2,5,numRows,1).getValues();
  var DataFeedbackCo1_Col5 = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getRange(2,6,numRows,1).getDisplayValues();

  sheetResultCheck.getRange(1,1, sheetResultCheck.getMaxRows(), sheetResultCheck.getMaxColumns()).clear({contentsOnly: true}).clearFormat();

  var new_arr_all = DataFeedbackCo1_Col0.map((e,i) => {return [e,DataFeedbackCo1_Col1[i],DataFeedbackCo1_Col2[i],DataFeedbackCo1_Col3[i],DataFeedbackCo1_Col4[i],DataFeedbackCo1_Col5[i],DataFeedbackCo1_Col0Display[i],DataFeedbackCo1_Col0Time[i]];})

  var DataCol1flat = DataFeedbackCo1_Col1.flat(); 

  const Arr_flat2 = [...DataCol1flat];
  const unique = (value,index,self) => {return self.indexOf(value) ===index;}  ;
  var Unique_List=Arr_flat2.filter(unique); 
  
 
  var Arr_all_results_for_Co1 = new Array();

  for (let index = 0, len = Unique_List.length ; index < len; ++index){ 
      const TargetDate = Unique_List[index];
      var Arr_result_TargetDate = new Array ();
      new_arr_all.map(function(Dat){if (Dat[1]==TargetDate){Arr_result_TargetDate.push([Dat[0], Dat[1], Dat[2], Dat[3], Dat[4], Dat[5], Dat[6], Dat[7] ] ) } });

      var Arr_Target_Date_col =new Array();
      new_arr_all.map(function(Dat){if (Dat[1]==TargetDate){Arr_Target_Date_col.push([Dat[7] ] ) } });
      
      var Arr_result_targetDate_latestresponse = Arr_Target_Date_col.flat();

      var max = Arr_result_targetDate_latestresponse.reduce(function(a, b) {
                           return new Date(a) > new Date(b) ? a : b;
                                     })
      // various attempts to filter for the latest response
      let filtered_arr_per_TargetDate = Arr_result_TargetDate.filter (row => row[7]===max);
      var nextemptyrow = sheetResultCheck.getLastRow()+1;
      sheetResultCheck.getRange(nextemptyrow,1,1,1).setValue('filtered_arr_per_TargetDate');
      sheetResultCheck.getRange(nextemptyrow+1,1,filtered_arr_per_TargetDate.length,filtered_arr_per_TargetDate[0].length).setValues(filtered_arr_per_TargetDate);
      
      var filtered_arr_per_TargetDate2 =  new Array();
      Arr_result_TargetDate.map(function (Dat){  if (Dat[7]==max)   {filtered_arr_per_TargetDate2.push([Dat[0], Dat[1], Dat[2], Dat[3], Dat[4], Dat[5], Dat[6], Dat[7]   ])}});
      // Logger.log("filtered_arr_per_TargetDate2"+filtered_arr_per_TargetDate2);

      var nextemptyrow = sheetResultCheck.getLastRow()+1;
      sheetResultCheck.getRange(nextemptyrow,1,1,1).setValue('filtered_arr_per_TargetDate2');
      sheetResultCheck.getRange(nextemptyrow+1,1,filtered_arr_per_TargetDate2.length,filtered_arr_per_TargetDate2[0].length).setValues(filtered_arr_per_TargetDate2);


      var filtered_arr_per_TargetDate3 =  Arr_result_TargetDate.filter(function(item){return item[7] === max;})
      // Logger.log("filtered_arr_per_TargetDate3 :"+filtered_arr_per_TargetDate3);

      var nextemptyrow = sheetResultCheck.getLastRow()+1;
      sheetResultCheck.getRange(nextemptyrow,1,1,1).setValue('filtered_arr_per_TargetDate3');
      sheetResultCheck.getRange(nextemptyrow+1,1,filtered_arr_per_TargetDate3.length,8).setValues(filtered_arr_per_TargetDate3);

      let Arr_result_TargetDateKopie = Arr_result_TargetDate.slice();
      var filtered_arr_per_TargetDate4 = Arr_result_TargetDateKopie.filter(function(item){return item[7] === max;});
      var nextemptyrow = sheetResultCheck.getLastRow()+1;
      sheetResultCheck.getRange(nextemptyrow,1,1,1).setValue('filtered_arr_per_TargetDate4');
      sheetResultCheck.getRange(nextemptyrow+1,1,filtered_arr_per_TargetDate4.length,8).setValues(filtered_arr_per_TargetDate4);

      

      Arr_all_results_for_Co1.push(...filtered_arr_per_TargetDate); 
    }
  
  Logger.log("Arr_all_results_for_Co1"+Arr_all_results_for_Co1);


It finds all of the TargetDates
it finds the latest response to each TargetDate
but it only returns the last row of the set an not all 19
what am i missing?
I appreciate any help
edit 1:
table of the raw data
example of multiple responses per TargetDate
edit 2
wanted output

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your input and output values from your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

nothing to apologize for, i added some screenshots to clarify

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Organizing 2d Array based upon date in column 2
function summarizeData(arr=[["ts","01/01/2024","c","d","e","f","g"],["ts","01/01/2024","c","d","e","f","g"],["ts","01/02/2024","c","d","e","f","g"],["ts","01/02/2024","c","d","e","f","g"],["ts","01/02/2024","c","d","e","f","g"],["ts","01/03/2024","c","d","e","f","g"],["ts","01/03/2024","c","d","e","f","g"],["ts","01/03/2024","c","d","e","f","g"]]) {
  const obj = arr.reduce((o, [a, b, c, d, e, f, g], i) => {
    let dt = new Date(b);
    let p = Utilities.formatDate(dt, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");
    if (!o.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      o[p] = [[a, c, d, e, f, g]];
      o.pA.push(p)
    } else {
      o[p].push([a, c, d, e, f, g])
    }
    return o;
  }, { pA: [] });
  let oA = [];
    obj.pA.forEach(p => {
      oA.push([p,"","","","",""])
      obj[p].forEach(e => {
        oA.push(e)
      })
    });
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(oA).replace(/],/g,'],\n'))
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    let sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    sh.clearContents();
    sh.getRange(1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}

Execution log
6:15:13 PM  Notice  Execution started
6:15:12 PM  Info    [["01/01/2024","","","","",""],
["ts","c","d","e","f","g"],
["ts","c","d","e","f","g"],
["01/02/2024","","","","",""],
["ts","c","d","e","f","g"],
["ts","c","d","e","f","g"],
["ts","c","d","e","f","g"],
["01/03/2024","","","","",""],
["ts","c","d","e","f","g"],
["ts","c","d","e","f","g"],
["ts","c","d","e","f","g"]]
6:15:15 PM  Notice  Execution completed

Active Sheet:




A
B
C
D
E
F




1
01/01/2024







2
ts
c
d
e
f
g


3
ts
c
d
e
f
g


4
01/02/2024







5
ts
c
d
e
f
g


6
ts
c
d
e
f
g


7
ts
c
d
e
f
g


8
01/03/2024







9
ts
c
d
e
f
g


10
ts
c
d
e
f
g


11
ts
c
d
e
f
g




Array.reduce()
google-apps-script reference
Utilities.formatDate()


try:
function getStringDSabcs() {
  var sol = [];
  var abcd = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("tests");

  // Get the values from the specified range
  const numbers2D = sh.getRange(12, 3, 1, 4).getValues();

  // Flatten the 2D array to a 1D array
  const numbers1D = numbers2D.reduce((acc, row) => acc.concat(row), []);
  console.log(numbers1D); // Log the array for debugging

  // Process each number in the array
  numbers1D.forEach(function (number) {
    console.log(number); // Log each number for debugging
    var lastChar = number.charAt(number.length - 1);
    var firstPart = number.substring(0, number.length - 1);
    console.log("Phần đầu mỗi chuỗi là: " + firstPart + " và phần cuối là: " + lastChar);
    sol.push(lastChar);
    abcd.push(firstPart);
    console.log(sol); // Log the sol array for debugging
    console.log(abcd); // Log the abcd array for debugging
  });

  // Update the ranges after processing the data
  sh.getRange(1, 3, 1, 4).setValues([abcd]);
  sh.getRange(2, 3, 1, 4).setValues([sol]);
}

function filterLatestEntries() {
  var sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('YourSheetName');
  var numRows = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getLastRow() - 1;

  var DataFeedbackCo1_Col0 = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getRange(2, 1, numRows, 1).getValues();
  var DataFeedbackCo1_Col0Time = DataFeedbackCo1_Col0.map(Dat => [Dat[0] * 1]);
  var DataFeedbackCo1_Col0Display = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getRange(2, 1, numRows, 1).getDisplayValues();
  var DataFeedbackCo1_Col1 = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getRange(2, 2, numRows, 1).getDisplayValues();
  var DataFeedbackCo1_Col2 = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getRange(2, 3, numRows, 1).getDisplayValues();
  var DataFeedbackCo1_Col3 = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getRange(2, 4, numRows, 1).getDisplayValues();
  var DataFeedbackCo1_Col4 = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getRange(2, 5, numRows, 1).getValues();
  var DataFeedbackCo1_Col5 = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getRange(2, 6, numRows, 1).getDisplayValues();

  var new_arr_all = DataFeedbackCo1_Col0.map((e, i) => [e, DataFeedbackCo1_Col1[i], DataFeedbackCo1_Col2[i], DataFeedbackCo1_Col3[i], DataFeedbackCo1_Col4[i], DataFeedbackCo1_Col5[i], DataFeedbackCo1_Col0Display[i], DataFeedbackCo1_Col0Time[i]]);

  var DataCol1flat = DataFeedbackCo1_Col1.flat();
  var Unique_List = [...new Set(DataCol1flat)];

  var Arr_all_results_for_Co1 = [];

  for (let index = 0; index < Unique_List.length; index++) {
    const TargetDate = Unique_List[index];
    var Arr_result_TargetDate = new_arr_all.filter(Dat => Dat[1] == TargetDate);

    var latestTimestamp = Arr_result_TargetDate.reduce((max, Dat) => new Date(Dat[7]) > new Date(max[7]) ? Dat : max, Arr_result_TargetDate[0])[7];

    var filtered_arr_per_TargetDate = Arr_result_TargetDate.filter(Dat => Dat[7] === latestTimestamp);
    Arr_all_results_for_Co1.push(...filtered_arr_per_TargetDate);
  }

  // Clear and update the result sheet
  var sheetResultCheck = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('ResultSheetName');
  sheetResultCheck.clear();

  var Headers = [["ResponseDateTimedisplay", "TargetDate", "Bereich", "Shift", "Quantity", "Supplier", "ResponseDateTimevalue"]];
  sheetResultCheck.getRange(1, 1, 1, 7).setValues(Headers);

  var nextemptyrow = sheetResultCheck.getLastRow() + 1;
  sheetResultCheck.getRange(nextemptyrow, 1, Arr_all_results_for_Co1.length, Arr_all_results_for_Co1[0].length).setValues(Arr_all_results_for_Co1);

  Logger.log("Arr_all_results_for_Co1: " + Arr_all_results_for_Co1);
}


I dont know what caused the problem
Anyway, I started at the beginning and I found a way for me
What I changed is at the beginning. Now I retrieve the raw data in one piece (not by separate columns)
Then I modify the ResponseDateTime column and TargetDate column by simply multiplying it with 1, and adding it to a new modified array.
After that I was able to filter the raw data with the Target Dates (all uniques) and with the latest responseDatetime of each target Date.
Then each filtered array is added to the destination array.
(The idea was to process the filtering within script. I expect it to be faster than doing it in sheets, when it comes to large amounts of data)
function GetCoSupplierData () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sheetresults = ss.getSheetByName ('Feedback_CoLi');  
  // var sheetResultCheck = ss.getSheetByName ('ErgebnisCheck'); // for debugging
  var sheetconfig = ss.getSheetByName('Config');
  var LinkCoLi1 = sheetconfig.getRange('D1').getValue();
  var FileCollectionCoLi1 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(LinkCoLi1);
  var sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1 = FileCollectionCoLi1.getSheetByName('Sammlung_waskoennensieliefern')
  var numRows = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getLastRow()-1;
  var DataFeedbackCo1_allCol = sheetCollectionFeedbackCoLi1.getRange(2,1,numRows,6).getValues();

  var DataFeedbackCo1_allColmodified = new Array ();
      DataFeedbackCo1_allCol.map(function(Dat){{DataFeedbackCo1_allColmodified.push([Dat[0], Dat[1], Dat[2], Dat[3], Dat[4], Dat[5], Dat[0]*1 , Dat[1]*1 ]) } });

  sheetresults.getRange(1,1,sheetresults.getMaxRows(),sheetresults.getMaxColumns()).clear({contentsOnly: true}).clearFormat();
  // sheetResultCheck.getRange(1,1, sheetResultCheck.getMaxRows(), sheetResultCheck.getMaxColumns()).clear({contentsOnly: true}).clearFormat(); // for debugging
  var Headers = [[ "ResponseDateTimedisplay", "TargetDate", "Bereich", "Shift", "Quantity","Supplier","ResponseDateTimevalue","TargetDateValue" ]]; ;
  sheetresults.getRange(1,1,1,8).setValues(Headers);
  // sheetResultCheck.getRange(1,1,1,8).setValues(Headers); for debugging

  // var nextemptyrow = sheetResultCheck.getLastRow()+1; // for debugging
  // sheetResultCheck.getRange(nextemptyrow,1,1,1).setValue('DatafeedbackCo1_allmodified'); // for debugging
  // sheetResultCheck.getRange(nextemptyrow+1,1,DataFeedbackCo1_allColmodified.length,8).setValues(DataFeedbackCo1_allColmodified); // for debugging

  var DataFeedbackCo1_Col1 = new Array();
      DataFeedbackCo1_allCol.map(function(Dat){{DataFeedbackCo1_Col1.push([ Dat[1]*1] ) } }); // only the column with the target date, but as value in milliseconds
  //    Logger.log(DataFeedbackCo1_Col1); // for Debugging

  // one way to get the unique items out of an array ************************************************************

  var DataCol1flat = DataFeedbackCo1_Col1.flat(); // flattens 

  const Arr_flat2 = [...DataCol1flat]; // i dont know if neccesary but worked for me
  const unique = (value,index,self) => {return self.indexOf(value) ===index;}  ;
  var Unique_List=Arr_flat2.filter(unique); // gets the unique items)

  // var nextemptyrow = sheetResultCheck.getLastRow()+1; // for Debugging
  // sheetResultCheck.getRange(nextemptyrow,1,1,1).setValue('Unique_List'); // for Debugging
  // sheetResultCheck.getRange(nextemptyrow+1,1,1,Unique_List.length).setValues([Unique_List]); // for Debugging

  // **********************************************************************************************************************************

  var Arr_all_results_for_Co1 = new Array();
  for (let index = 0, len = Unique_List.length ; index < len; ++index){ // loop through the unique items of Target Date
    const TargetDate = Unique_List[index];
    // console.log("processed TargetDate:"+TargetDate); //prints the processed TargetDate // for debugging

    // filter the raw data just by TargetDate 
    var filteredData1 = DataFeedbackCo1_allColmodified.filter(function(item){return item[7] === TargetDate  ;});
    // Logger.log("filteredData1"+filteredData1); // for debugging
    // var nextemptyrow = sheetResultCheck.getLastRow()+1; // for debugging
    // sheetResultCheck.getRange(nextemptyrow,1,1,1).setValue('filteredData1'); // for debugging
    // sheetResultCheck.getRange(nextemptyrow+1,1,filteredData1.length,8).setValues(filteredData1); // for debugging

    // retrieving the responseDateTime and finding the latest

    var Arr_Target_Date_col =new Array();
    filteredData1.map(function(Dat){{Arr_Target_Date_col.push([Dat[6] ] ) } }); // need only the responseDateTime , again the one which is in milliseconds
    var Arr_result_targetDate_latestresponse = Arr_Target_Date_col.flat();
    var max = Arr_result_targetDate_latestresponse.reduce(function(a, b) {
                           return new Date(a) > new Date(b) ? a : b;
                                     })
    // Logger.log("max:"+max); // for debugging

    // filter the raw data with both criteria at the same time

    var filteredData2 = DataFeedbackCo1_allColmodified.filter(function(item){return item[7] === TargetDate && item[6]=== max ;});
    // var nextemptyrow = sheetResultCheck.getLastRow()+1; // for debugging
    // sheetResultCheck.getRange(nextemptyrow,1,1,1).setValue('filteredData2'); // for debugging
    // sheetResultCheck.getRange(nextemptyrow+1,1,filteredData2.length,8).setValues(filteredData2); // for debugging

    Arr_all_results_for_Co1.push(...filteredData2); //adds the final target date data to the results of destination array
    
  }
  
  sheetresults.getRange(2,1,Arr_all_results_for_Co1.length,8).setValues(Arr_all_results_for_Co1);
  
}



